# How to unsubmit pending chrome extension & how to delete extension draft

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I was wondering how I could unsubmit a pending chrome extension review since I had made a mistake but I'm not sure how to unsubmit it. Furthermore, I have some drafts of extension uploads that I dont care about and was unsure how how to delete it entirely.